# PHP Loop Per Tens

Tags: php, for-loop

How to make loop per tens like this one,

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) { 
    if ($i == 1 || $ == 2 ... $i == 10) {
        # code...
    } elseif ($i == 11 || $ == 12 ... $i == 20) {
        # code...
    } else {
        # code...
    }

}
```

I need 1 2 3 4 5 is different from 11 12 13 14 15 and 21 22 23 24 25

Comment: also, the problem with your current code is that the first iteration is `$i=0`, so it will go to your `else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could approach this :

**1. Separate them**

Since clearly, you're doing different code to the ranges 1-10, 11-20, a,d 21-30, then it would do you good to separate them into several for loops.

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) { 
    //code for $i 1-10
}

for ($i=11; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
    //code for $i 11-20
}

for ($i=21; $i <= 30; $i++) { 
    //code for $i 21-30
}
```

**2. Put the conditionals inside one for loop, but use <= instead of ==**

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 30; $i++) { 
    if($i <= 10){
        //code for $i 1-10
    }
    else if($i <= 20){
       // code for $i 11-20
    }
    else{
       // code for $i 21-30
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `$i > 0 && $i <= 10` for the `if` conditions if you prefer or for readability, but the above code does exactly the same with less.

Personally, for your specific example, I would prefer using the **first option**, as it is much more readable (for me).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    switch (floor($i / 10)) {
        case 0:

        break;
        case 1:

        break;
        default:

        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing int vs float :)